# Soundcloud HTML5 player in ios

Tags: javascript, html, ios, soundcloud

I'm trying to make custom buttons for the soundcloud player in ios, it works on all other platforms.
Can someone please tell me why my toggle button dosen't work under ios, Safari?

The skip buttons works perfectly, also the sound start playing if I hit the players own (red) toggle button. After pressing this, and the audio plays, my toggle button also starts to work . Seems like it won't accept the first javascript call to be from my custom button.

```
<body>
        <iframe id="iframe" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/users/calvinharris&color=ed1c24&show_comments=false&show_artwork=false" class="iframe"
          width= "320px"
          height="567px"
          scrolling="no"
          frameborder="no">
        </iframe>

     <button onclick="prev()"><<</button>
     <button onclick="toggle()">|> ||</button>
     <button onclick="next()">>></button>

    <script src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">

var iframe = document.querySelector('.iframe');
iframe.src = "http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/users/calvinharris&color=ed1c24&show_comments=false&show_artwork=false";
var widget = SC.Widget(iframe);

function toggle(){
    widget.toggle();
}

function next(){
    widget.next();              
}

function prev(){
    widget.prev();      
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```